# Get specific line with beautifulsoup using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've watched this video which he **scraped** an article from his website, https://youtu.be/ng2o98k983k?t=2317
But the thing missing in the video is that he didn't explain how I can **scrape** a specific line in loop from the article.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('http://coreyms.com').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    headline = article.h2.a.text
    print(headline)

    summary = article.find('div', class_='entry-content').p.text
    print(summary)

    try:
        vid_src = article.find('iframe', class_='youtube-player')['src']

        vid_id = vid_src.split('/')[4]
        vid_id = vid_id.split('?')[0]

        yt_link = f'https://youtube.com/watch?v={vid_id}'
    except Exception as e:
        yt_link = None

    print(yt_link)

    print()
```

I did this `vid_src = article.find('iframe', class_='youtube-player')['src'][1]`
but it doesn't work.

Comment: What _exactly_ are you trying to scrape? Why are you doing `['src'][1]`?

Comment: @MendelG When he loop the article he scrapped all the articles like the contents and src vids ..etc https://youtu.be/ng2o98k983k?t=2121 the thing that I want is I want to scrap a specific line from all these lines, hope you get it

Comment: What line specifically do you want?

Comment: The `Linux/Mac Terminal Tutorial: How to use the rsync Command ......` line

Comment: I don't see that on https://coreyms.com/. Maybe it's under a different page number?

Comment: @MendelG Yes, it is on a different page, it does not matter all of this, the most important thing is that I want to scrap a specific line, and not all lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you can search for the tag based on it's text. For example, here we search or an `a` with the text "Python Tutorial: Zip Files – Creating and Extracting Zip Archives":

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


source = requests.get("http://coreyms.com").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

my_tag = soup.find(
    lambda tag: tag.name == "a"
    and "Python Tutorial: Zip Files – Creating and Extracting Zip Archives"
    in tag.text.strip()
).text

print(my_tag)
```

Output:

```
Python Tutorial: Zip Files – Creating and Extracting Zip Archives
```